# Labview Instrument Error: A service request has not been received for the session

Tags: labview

I'm trying to get a [Labview VI](https://github.com/jhaase1/labview) working. However, I'm getting an error on the KE6485 Multi-read sub-VI with the error "Driver Status: (Hex 0xBFFF004A) Error - A service request has not been received for the session". Does anyone have a suggestion on steps I could take to fix this?

Comment: Would you place the VI or a screenshot in a spot where a reader doesn't need to register for a service?

Comment: Sorry about that, I put it on Github

Comment: Thanks! Would you add a little more information -- when was the last time this VI worked correctly? What things might have changed since then? Are you able to use an example VI (see `LabVIEW XXXX\instr.lib\KE6485\KE6485 Examples.llb`) with your instrument successfully?

Comment: It was a couple of months ago because I had a couple of pieces of equipment down. The examples don't work. Additionally, the expected dependency path (C:\VXlpnp\WINNT\Bin\KE6485_32.DLL) isn't the new dependency path (KE6485_32.DLL)

Comment: These are good details to add to your question. I don't have a clear enough understanding yet to make any suggestions, but it seems like the failure mode for your VI (error from driver) is different than for the examples (can't [load dependency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876326/dll-load-error-in-labview-2011)). Any more characterization of the problem you can provide will help.